# mysqldump before and after to compare Database content during verification of new software

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm testing a method of checking that our DB doesn't lose or gain anything new with software changes by dumping the DB before and after and diffing the outputs. As a practice, I simply create a software snapshot with zero changes so that the expected output is no differences.

First we dump the empty DB

```
sudo mysqldump statsdb > /var/tmp/emptyStatsDb
```

I then process a data file against latest version of our software

```
mysqldump statsdb > /var/tmp/statsdbBefore
```

Empty the Database

```
mysql statsdb < /var/tmp/emptyStatsDb
```

Then we process the SNAPSHOT version with proposed changes before dumping the DB again

```
mysqldump statsdb > /var/tmp/statsdbAfter
```

We then diff the 2 files.

```
diff /var/tmp/statsdbBefore /var/tmp/statsdbAfter
```

However, I get many, many differences reported. I'm not sure why. Are my commands correct for what I'm doing.